# GlobalHost dependency injection for non signalr component

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, signalr

As I am using old ASP.NET Signalr 2.4.x, I notice there is in-built dependency injection package called 'GlobalHost.DependencyResolver'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Any article related to this component explains dependency injection for SignalR but at the same time, when they explain dependency injection in general, they show examples of non SignalR classes, which confuses me and might giving me a wrong hope.

I wonder if this GlobalHost can actually help dependency injection of non SignalR classes as well.